# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison - sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

Tags: python, recursion, recursionerror

I am doing a Python exercise using recursion.
The goal is to request which maximum value the user wants to study and to test all the values from 1 to this maximum value. The algorithm always reachs 1 or 4. The program stops when those values are reached and then returns one of those values.

I wanted to use a recursive approach here but I have an issue with the maximum recursion depth.

The program only works for numbers 1 and 2 :

```
C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop
λ python algo.py
Enter a number > 0 1
vect1 =  [1]
vect4 =  []

C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop
λ python algo.py
Enter a number > 0 2
vect1 =  [1]
vect4 =  [2]
```

I have founded suggestions asking to extend the maximum recursion depth that I have extented to 1500 but that is still not working.

> [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
>
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

I have also tried iterative approach but I have issue :

```
  def recursive(s, n):
        while n != 0:
            s = s + (n % 10)**2
            n = n // 10
        if s == 1 or s == 4:
            return s
        else:
            return recursive(s, n)
```

Would you have any advices or tips ? Thank you in advance

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

class Error(Exception):
    """ Base class for exceptions """
    pass

class StrictlypPositive(Error):
    """ Called when the number is lower than 1 """
    pass

def recursive(s, n):
    if s == 1 or s == 4:
        return s
    else:
        s = s + (n % 10)**2
        n = n // 10
        return recursive(s, n)

vect1 = []
vect4 = []

while True:
    try:
        maxVal = int(input("Enter a number > 0 ").strip('n'))
        if maxVal < 1:
            raise StrictlypPositive
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number")
    except StrictlypPositive:
        print("Enter a number strictly positive")

for val in range(1, maxVal + 1):
    theSum = 0
    theSum = recursive(theSum, val)
    if theSum == 1:
        vect1.append(val)
    else:
        vect4.append(val)

print("vect1 = ", vect1)
print("vect4 = ", vect4)
```

Comment: In short, even if you set recursion limit to 1 millions, the error will still happen. This can be oberserved by setting ```n``` to ```3```, for instance, the first loop will be sucessful but thereafter will keep looping infinitely because ```n``` has become ```0``` (```3 // 10```).

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed I forgot to add the test while n != 0

Comment: That could be the solution, but I think the biggest culprit is due to use of ```//```.

Comment: Tangentially, no need to declare a base class for your exception, and no need to assign 0 to `theSum` when you then immediately assign another value to it.

Comment: Hello @tripleee the algorithm starts with 'theSum' initialized to 0. I need to keep it for each number (called val) I will be studying. 'theSum' variable receives then 1 or 4 when the recursive function ends. Regarding the base class how can I do ? I have tried without the base class but I had an issue '    except StrictlypPositive:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed'

Comment: But `StrictlypPositive` can inherit directly from `Exception`; there is no need to have an intermediate class just for it to inherit from.

Comment: `theSum = 0; theSum = recursive(theSum, val)` will immediately overwrite the 0 with whatever the recursive function returns. The first assignment is useless.  Just call `theSum = recursive(0, val)`.

Comment: Hello @tripleee I have updated the code in my program and I hope all is fine in the edit I have done in stackoverflow. I am still have an issue with the recursive function. Indeed for 13 number the program stops because n ends with 0. I would like to recall the recursive function and I have tried to make a test but it doesn't work at all. Would you have any idea ? thank you in advance

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. Please don't move the goalposts. Accept the answer you got (or post one of your own and accept that), then ask a new question about your new problem. Probably this time don't forget to explain what the function should actually do.

Comment: Thank you very much @tripleee how can I accept your edit ? Sorry I am new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a simple `print` in the recursive function reveals an endless loop.

```
Enter a number > 0: 3
recurse: s 1, n 0
recurse: s 4, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
recurse: s 9, n 0
```

It's not clear what the calculation should properly produce, but having it not recurse when the new values are identical to the old values should at least avoid the immediate symptom.

In the general case, when code doesn't do what you expect, add a `print` where you think it's going wrong, and see what it does.